# Execute Stored Procedure using Context.Database.SqlQuery<T> and Complex Type mapping

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, mapping, ef-code-first, complextype

I have a class called Product with this structure:

```
    public class Product
  {
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Summary { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public long ProductCategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }

    public ConstantPost ConstantPost { get; set; }

  }
```

there is a complex type called ConstantPost. 
when i want to execute a Stored Procedure called MostBought i get this error:
**Cannot create a value for property 'ConstantPost' of type 'Domain.ConstantPost'. Only properties with primitive types are supported.**

how can i ignore complex types when executing stored procedures.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported at the moment. You cannot return entity containing complex types from `SqlQuery`.

Comment: thanks. i think i should create another model for retriving my data.

Comment: I simply can't believe that this isn't supported. This seems like a relatively common way to store data. Storing, updating and deleting data work perfectly with the proper `ModelBuilder` information, so I'm not sure I understand why pulling data back with a store procedure in the exact same format results in this error. There isn't any other way to solve this other than writing a redundant model?

Comment: @Eric: Try to use `SqlQuery` on `DbSet` instance.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka, can you elaborate on that? Calling `SqlQuery` directly on the `DbSet` instance produces the same error.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka any plans to implement it in EF7?